# Get master commit from submodule commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, git-commit, git-tag

I have master repository with 2 submodules in it. When I do `git submodule status` in master it gives me the recent commit in submodules. But how will I get the corresponding commit of master.

I can only see that when I do `git log`

Example:

```
commit d111aeec...........28a7
Author: <author_name>
Date:   Mon Sep 24 17:01:01 2018 +0200

    Updated submodules: submodule1 -> ( 45d60a5 ) 

    Submodule 'submodule1 ' commits:
    *  45d60a5  - Some commit (author_name)
```

I need **d111aeec...........28a7**. I have **45d60a5**.

**Edit:** The reason behind asking this is in my project I have a tagging mechanism which tags the submodule commits. I need the same tag to the corresponding commit in super repository. If anyone can help me with this?

Comment: How about grepping `git log` then?

Comment: The problem is I cannot just pick up the recent commit and grep out of it. I want to get the corresponding master commit for which I have submodule commit number

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple superproject commits that use the *same* submodule commit from that submodule.

If we gave each superproject commit and subproject commit a person's name, that would mean, for instance, that subproject commit Bob is at the dance, but on Monday Alice brought Bob, and on Wednesday, Carol brought Bob.  If I show you a snapshot of Bob being at the dance and ask you: *Who brought him?* will you say Alice, or Carol?

All that said, you can use `git rev-parse` on each superproject commit:

```
searchfor=$(git rev-parse HEAD)   # in submodule
cd ../../                         # as many ../-es as needed to get to superproject
git rev-list --branches | while read rev; do
    if [ $(git rev-parse $rev:path/to/submodule) = $searchfor ]; then
        echo superproject commit $rev uses submodule commit $searchfor
    fi
done
```

This is the equivalent of looking at *every* snapshot to see who brought Bob on *that* day.  You'll find both Alice *and* Carol, in effect.

(The script above is rather sloppy, and is untested—it's just meant to illustrate the method.)